# NGINX - Redirecting certain routes to a subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain

I created a project, where I have:

1. `my-project.com` to show my Angular 8 App
2. `api.my-project.com` to access my Symfony 5 API

I built a very basic landing page on my Angular app, but now, I changed my mind and I want to have my angular app into `app.my-project.com` and keep the `my-project.com` to show a beautifull landing page.

The problem is that there are some clients that are already using the service on the main domain, and that request should be redirected to the `app.my-project.com` subdomain.

Should be something like this:

`my-project.com/login` -> `app.my-project.com/login`

`my-project.com/pm-something` -> `app.my-project.com/pm-something`

Here is a pseudocode of what I need:

```
if( url.includes('login') or url.includes('pm-') ) {
    redirectTo(app.my-project.com)
}
```

I thought the easiest way to achieve that is to rewriting the routes in my NGINX config file, but I am not sure the correct way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX chooses request URI processing rules according to defined `location` blocks within the server configuration. Official documentation on this directive is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), and [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) are some additional explanations. You can achieve desired behavior using two prefix locations:

```
location /login {
    return 301 $scheme://app.my-project.com$request_uri;
}
location /pm- {
    return 301 $scheme://app.my-project.com$request_uri;
}
```

This two prefix locations could be replaced by a single regex matching location:

```
location ~ ^/(login|pm-) {
    return 301 $scheme://app.my-project.com$request_uri;
}
```

NGINX uses system PCRE library and the general PCRE regex syntax, except you should not use delimiter characters for regex patterns (matching against a regex specified using `~` (case-sensitive matching), `~*` (case-insensitive matching) or `!~`/`!~*` (case-sensitive/case-insensitive non-matching) operators). Additionally you are not required to prefix `/` character with a backslash (although you still can do it, it won't change the regex pattern meaning).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Hello Ivan, it worked! Could you please add some explanation on how it works? As @pppery said, it wold be great. Thanks!

Comment: @IsaacBosca Added some explanations.